# Jquery - Scroll left value based on variable

Tags: jquery, carousel

I have a basic carousel (horizontal overflowing grid) and have added right / left links and written a couple line of Jquery to allow for easy desktop navigation.

Here is my HTML

```html
<div class="userProfileCarousel">
  <div class ="carouselPrev">LEFT</div>
  <div class ="carouselNext">RIGHT</div>
  <a>Carousel content</a>
  <a>Carousel content</a>
  <a>Carousel content</a>
</div>
```

And my lines of jquery

```js
$(function() {
  var carouselWidth = $('.userProfileCarousel').width();
        
  $('.carouselPrev').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().find('.userProfileCarousel').animate({
      scrollLeft: -=carouselWidth()
    }, "slow");
  });
  $('.carouselNext').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.userProfileCarousel').animate({
      scrollLeft: +=carouselWidth()
    }, "slow");
  });
});
```

My issue is that I would like to use the 'carouselWidth' variable as my scroll left value but can't manage to get it to work. Can you help me spot my mistake here ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

First of all `carouselWidth` in your example is not a function, and you should remove round brackets at the end, otherwise it will causing an error.

Secondly when animating values you should use quotes for assigning new relative values.

Heres basic example of how animate an simple box:

```js
let $box = $('.box');
let width = $box.width();

$box.on('click', function() {
  $box.animate({
    left: '+=' + width
  })
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: salmon;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='box' />
```

Fixed your example - remove syntax errors, and remove unnecessary `preventDefault()` calls. Since you are attaching events to `div` elements there is no need to `preventDefault`. It would have sense if there was `a` instead of `div`.

```
$(function() {
  var carouselWidth = $('.userProfileCarousel').width();
        
  $('.carouselPrev').click(function(event) {
    $(this).parent().find('.userProfileCarousel').animate({
      scrollLeft: '-=' + carouselWidth
    }, "slow");
  });
  $('.carouselNext').click(function(event) {
    $(this).next('.userProfileCarousel').animate({
      scrollLeft: '+=' + carouselWidth
    }, "slow");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks ! Makes total sense. One clarification. I see that you have used a much simpler function than mine to trigger the scroll (no event.preventDefault function or event overall). Would it make sense for me to simplify my code as well ?

Comment: @JulienA actually I've copied\paste your code in the last example, so preventDefault are there. But in your case it is unnecessary to prevent default behaviour. I've updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: got it. Appreciate the time and effort.